# OpenERP email template

Tags: odoo

Please, I would like to know how to generate a dynamic image loading in a mail template.

For example, I have an image in an email that if loaded, it calls up a php code that output the stream and stores some information about the customer for tracking purposes.

Here is an example:

`<img src='http://domain/trk/index.php?src=img.jpg&email= ${object.email}&id=${...}' />`

The problem is, OpenERP does not replace the `object.email` with its value, it simply leaves the string as it is.

Comment: it will not because of `< >` which will be skipped while being evaluated. Check Jinja2 documentation how you can void it.

Comment: i checked Jinja2 Documentation but i can't figure out how to fix it :/

Comment: can you put your complete email template ?

Comment: here is the part of my email even 'this link' that i took from the example template does't work it's seems like a filter is applied to those dynamic values 
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/trk/index.php?ids=${object.user_id.id}&lien=www.google.comh&campagne=Demo_Campagne&" title="Domain tracking" />
<a href="${object.signup_url}">this link</a>

Answer (score 0):

Long time from this question was asked, but I have just faced the same problem, and I was able to solve it updating the whole branches of ocb-addons and ocb-server.

Go to the directory of **ocb-addons** and type:

`bzr pull` (if you're using ***Bazaar***)
or
`git pull` (if you're using ***Git***)

And then the same process for **ocb-server**.

Don't forget to restart and update the service after that.

Hope this answer helps to anyone. Regards!